# Passing variable to Modal window in Angular with Jade and CoffeeScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, pug

I am trying to pass a value from a page to a pop-up modal window but the browser gives me an undefined value. Following is my page controller function for the modal window

```
$scope.showUserDetails =  (user) ->
modalInstance = $modal.open
  templateUrl: "/partials/user_details.html"
  controller: "UserDetailCtrl"
  keyboard: true
  resolve:
      selectedUser: ->
        user

modalInstance.result.then (args) ->
    updateFilter()
```

and the following is my modal window controller

```
.controller('UserDetailCtrl', [
'$scope'
'$modalInstance'
'selectedUser'
($scope,$location,$http,$modalInstance,selectedUser) ->
    console.log(selectedUser);
    $scope.user = selectedUser;
])
```

But the variable selectedUser is always undefined. I even tried passing a string instead of the variable 'user' in the main controller but I still get an undefined value.

Comment: Like @muistooshort alluded to, I think you have a problem with the order of your dependencies in the `UserDetailCtrl` definition.  See this codepen I created inspired by your code and it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyvPyN

Comment: @JoseM: Hey thanks for the codepen. Its turns out, there in fact was a problem with the dependencies and your solution works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment you made, the issue was the dependencies that you listed.  In your controller function you had references to `$location` and `$http` but you didn't list them in the array of string names.  To fix you need to either remove them from your controller (if you aren't using them), or properly specify them in the string list.

Remove from controller

```
.controller('UserDetailCtrl', [
  '$scope'
  '$modalInstance'
  'selectedUser'
  ($scope,$modalInstance,selectedUser) ->
    console.log(selectedUser);
    $scope.user = selectedUser;
])
```

Or add to string list

```
.controller('UserDetailCtrl', [
  '$scope'
  '$location',
  '$http',
  '$modalInstance'
  'selectedUser'
  ($scope,$location,$http,$modalInstance,selectedUser) ->
    console.log(selectedUser);
    $scope.user = selectedUser;
])
```